# Is it possible to do a visibility analysis and create a 3d - cone as a result in ArcGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, 3d, visibility

I have a digital surface model of a region and the coordinates and height of an observer point and need to do a 3d - visibility analysis for this point.

However, as a result I would need a threedimensional 'visibility cone' (probably a multipart feature?) which depicts the areas that are visible, not only on the ground but also in the air (similar to the area confined by AZ1/AZ2, R1/R2, V1/V2 in this [image](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/GUID-6E9426D5-6274-4CBA-9BE6-E71DE9598F7D-web.gif).
I would also need to be able to set the various parameters like aperture angle, range etc.

Is doing something like this possible in ArcGIS?

[image]

Source: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/GUID-6E9426D5-6274-4CBA-9BE6-E71DE9598F7D-web.gif

Comment: Could you add the image to your question (giving proper attribution)? Otherwise it might get lost when the source removes it.

Comment: Check this video if it's what you are looking for: https://www.esri.com/videos/watch?videoid=282&title=3d-viewshed-analysis

Comment: Unfortunately not, I need to "see" further upwards than the skyline function allows and also to a specified distance (e.g. +/- 45° from the horizontal level for 30km unless the view is obstructed)

Comment: Please decide which of ArcGIS Desktop and QGIS you wish to ask about in this particular question. That will help focus your question and any answers on what you have tried and where you are stuck. You can always ask about the other product in a separate question.